# Rewrite string formatting without format function

Tags: python, format, string-formatting, python-2.4

I have this piece of code:

```
parse_string = \
    '&category={0}&v=2'.format('%2C+'.join(tag.strip() for tag in tags_list))
```

how can I rewrite this to be python 2.4 compatible (so the same functionality but without using format function) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this will do it:

```
'&category=%s&v=2' % '%2C+'.join(tag.strip() for tag in tags_list)
```